# Invoke ATL model transformation in MWE2

Tags: eclipse, mde, eclipse-atl

Is it possible to invoke an ATL model transformation within an MWE2 workflow?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. However you would have to implement a MWE2 workflow component that accomplishes that. Have a look at the ATL forum for [some Java code that programatically does a transformation](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/438623/).